# Prove $\binom{n}{i}< \binom{n}{j} $ if $0\leq i<j\leq \frac{n}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

For even $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove $\binom{n}{i}< \binom{n}{j} $ if $0\leq i<j\leq \frac{n}{2}$.

So far all I have been able to come up with are a bunch of seemingly useless inequalities.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: 
 $${n \choose j+1} = \frac{n-j}{j+1} {n \choose j} $$

Answer (score 2):

You can use induction on $n$ and the Pascal identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom{n-1}{k}$.

The only tricky case is when $j = \frac{n}{2}$, since then $j \not\leq \frac{n-1}{2}$, but you can use the fact that $\binom{n-1}{j} = \binom{n-1}{n-1-j} = \binom{n-1}{j-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Try proving
$$
\binom{n}{i} < \binom{n}{i + 1}
$$
by using the formula
$$
\binom{n}{i} = \frac{n!}{i! \cdot (n - i)!}.
$$

Comment: This doesn't always hold

Comment: It holds when $i+1 \leq \frac{n}{2}$  which was what I wanted.